# QEMU - network bridge

Tags: networking, kvm, qemu, bridge

I'm setting up a VM on Debian 9 using QEMU (and KVM). I'm currently trying to make it work through a bridged network, which I have set up using `ip link`, `ip tuntap` etc; here is the output of `brctl show`:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.107b444f55d6       no              enp4s0
                                                        tap0
docker0         8000.0242d4c18983       no
```

And here is the output of `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:7b:44:4f:55:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:d4:c1:89:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:54:bb:db:d7:c6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::f454:bbff:fedb:d7c6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:7b:44:4f:55:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.26/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::127b:44ff:fe4f:55d6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The `docker0` interface is unrelated.

As far as I can tell, this should be working. However, my Windows 8.1 guest within QEMU has no internet access, and is unable to acquire an IP over DHCP (I'm simply getting auto-generated 169.xx.xx.xx IPs).

I'm unsure as to why this is. My QEMU arguments are:

```
-net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0
```

and I've also tried:

```
-device e1000,netdev=net0,mac=52:55:00:d1:55:01 -netdev tap,id=net0
```

which both yield the same result of no network access. I can't figure this out.

Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: Are you using the VirtIO drivers?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No, should I be? Windows does detect the adapter, and it still doesn't work when I explicitly make it an e1000

Comment: I think so, but I am not that experienced with kvm *and* Windows.

Comment: Did you do all this stuff too? - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-qemu_guest_agent-running_the_qemu_guest_agent_on_a_windows_guest. Details about KVM networking - https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking.

Comment: @slm I haven't set up virtio drivers on the guest, no, but that shouldn't be an issue as I'm not using virtio devices. I did use the KVM networking page as a basis - in fact I followed their Public Bridge guide precisely to create the setup detailed in my post

Comment: Some leads - http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Talk:Using_QEMU_on_Windows.

Comment: Seems so simple, not sure what's tripping you up. This tutorial makes it seem trivial - https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/qemu-windows-guest-bridged-networking/#gref.

Comment: That tutorial shows this - `-netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000,netdev=net0`

Comment: @slm I've tried that command too, and the leads on laptop.org are about using Windows as the host rather than the guest

Comment: Does the hardware show up in windows?

Comment: @slm Yeah, Windows sees the network adapter just fine, but it fails to acquire an IP address over DHCP. (I've also tried setting a ststic one, but it still had no network access)

Comment: @MatthewLugg - OK, so that makes me think that it's Windows that's the problem then.  If Windows can see the device, perhaps it's the driver or configuration within Windows that's getting tripped up?

Comment: You can always debug: use tcpdump wherever you can (the tap0 interface, the bridge, etc.) and see what you can see when windows tries DHCP

Comment: Is the network adapter in the host wireless?

Comment: Which version of QEMU are you using? and have you specified `-machine q35` ? I might be seeing simlar issues but with a Linux guest, and it seems to be mutually breaking fixes in qemu 2.12 and newer Linux kernels.

Comment: I have the same problem, and while I've yet to figure out a final fix, the authors note of "The docker0 interface is unrelated." is untrue. Disabling docker at boot, rebooting fixed it for me. So we both need to find a way to specify the bridge device so that it doesn't try to use docker0.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a very similar problem with a QEMU Linux guest and it has turned out that iptables was blocking the traffic. If I set up a static IP address for the guest then the host and the guest could ping each other but that was it. The internet and the rest of my network couldn't be reached from the guest machine.

I highly recommend you to use something like Wireshark or tcpdump to investigate the problem.

I've captured the bridge interface from the host using Wireshark and it seemed like requests were coming out from the virtual machine but no response was received.

[image]

TL;DR:
This clue led me to the magic iptable commands (it was magical for me because I'm not experienced enough with iptables :)) in the following answer:

https://serverfault.com/a/165786

It worked and even if I don't fully understand it at this very moment I thought I would leave my two cents here.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am currently struggling with this problem as well. I've come a bit closer to the solution than you.

I am on Debian 10 and I decidd to only use the a package `iproute2` (`ip link`, `ip addr`, `bridge link`...) which is part of a kernel and will be available on any Linux.  and package `qemu-kvm`. This is everything you need.

---

---

---

### STEP 1

Open **1st terminal** and write this down, so that you will be able to see your progres:

```
while true; do ip addr; sleep 1; clear; done
```

---

---

---

### STEP 2

Open **2nd terminal** and execute these commmands while you look at the progress in the **1st terminal**:

```
sudo ip link add virtual_bridge type bridge
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge up
```

And you have a bridge which is `up`.

---

---

---

### JUST AN EXPERIMENT BEFORE YOU CONTINUE

Your `virtual_bridge` is now `up` but your ethernet card might be `up` or `down`. Now read these two scenarios I figured out by trial and error. It is very important **(!)** so that you will understand how your ethernet card reacts. You might try this or not, but I advise you to do it exactly like described below while watching the **1st terminal** for changes.

**Scenario A:**

If your ethernet card is `down` try to assign a master to it with a command below. It will work:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 master virtual_bridge
```

and now turn it on:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 up
```

you will be surprised that card won't connect you to the internet. It won't make it even if you restart it:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 down
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 up
```

and not even if you restart the bridge that is card's master who should control it:

```
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge down
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge up
```

the only way I managed to make it connect to the internet was to restart the card, remove the master, flush it to remove all IP *(maybe this isn't needed)*, manualy assign a known & working IP and then assign the master:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 down
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 up
sudo ip addr flush enx24f5a2f17b27
sudo ip addr add 192.168.64.100/24 dev enx24f5a2f17b27
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 master virtual_bridge
```

At this point internet should start working.

**Scenario B:**

If your ethernet card is `up` it probably has an IP and your internet must be working. So now try to assign it a master with a command below. It will work!

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 master virtual_bridge
```

Now reset the bridge multiple times and pay attention what happens to a card:

```
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge down
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge up
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge down
sudo ip link set virtual_bridge up
```

You will see that whenever you enable the bridge ethernet card will also be enabled, it will get IP and connect to the internet. But once you turn off the card:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 down
```

it won't be able to reconect to the internet no mater how many times you reset the bridge.

> So this is why it is most important that you **first** turn on the ethernet card and **second** asign it a master and not the other way around! In other words card should be enabled when you are assigning a master.

---

---

---

### STEP 3

As we learned from the example above, we first **(!)** turn on the ethernet card which will get an IP:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 up
```

and then we assign it a master:

```
sudo ip link set enx24f5a2f17b27 master virtual_bridge
```

we create a TAP device which is like a virtual ethernet card for the virtual machine. It is important **(!)** that you assign a `user` and a `group` to it, because it might not have proper privileges otherwise:

```
sudo ip tuntap add virtual_tap mode tap user ziga group ziga
```

Now that you created it, you can try to enable it, but you won't suceed, because only virtual machine can do that:

```
sudo ip link set virtual_tap up
```

so it will remain in the `down` state. Just apply the master to it as well:

```
sudo ip link set virtual_tap master virtual_bridge
```

and you are done with setting up the network. Pay attention that at this point your TAP device won't have IP. It will be assigned to it when you start the virtual machine and wait for virtual machine to set itself up.

---

---

---

### STEP 4

Now it is time to properly start the virtual machine. I do it using the newest `-nic` command which is shorter and more capable **(!)** than old commands ([read](https://www.qemu.org/2018/05/31/nic-parameter/)). Well anyway... I use this command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp cores=3,threads=1 -m 4096 -nic tap,ifname=virtual_tap,script=no,downscript=no -boot order=c -cdrom ~/Dropbox/workspace/racunalnistvo/programi/kvm/iso/centos-8.1.1911-x86_64-dvd1.iso -drive file=~/Dropbox/workspace/racunalnistvo/programi/kvm/vm/windows.qcow2,format=qcow2
```

> If you ommit options `script=no`  and `downscript=no` the above comand
>   will return a harmless warning:
>
> ```
> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
> W: /etc/qemu-ifup: no bridge for guest interface found
> ```
>
> which happens because prior to emulation Qemu tryies to auto set up
>   it's own bridge & TAP with a script `/etc/qemu-ifup`. It will also try
>   to remove the bridge & TAP after it is finished with a script
>   `/etc/qemu-ifdown`. If you look into these scripts you will see that
>   they use command `brctl` which is part of a package `bridge-utils`
>   that I don't have installed and scripts fail!
>
> We created the bridge & TAP devices manually anyway so we don't need
>   those scripts and we prevent Qemu to call them with `script=no` and
>   `downscript=no`.
>
> It would be interesting to rewrite these scripts to use `iproute2`
>   instead of `bridge-utils` but you would need `root` privileges to run
>   them and experts disadvise us running virtual machines as `root`.

Virtual machine will start, connect to the internet, but it won't be able to ping host! Also the host will be able to connect to the internet and will be able to ping the same gateway. But it won't be able to ping a virtual machine!

Also pay attention to the **1st terminal** where you will see that TAP device is now enabled and it got an IP, but this IP here is different than the one you see from inside the virtual machine! Can anyone explain this?

---

---

---

### TODO

This is how much I was able to figure out and I hope it helps someone. I stil don't know why host and virtual machine can't ping eachother as TAP device should enable TCP, UDP & ICMP... I suspect that it is because I have to somehow assign IP to the bridge ([read](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge#Assigning_an_IP_address), [read](https://serverfault.com/questions/165762/no-arp-reply-on-tap0-kvm-bridged-networking/165786#326089)) but I don't know how to choose the right one. Can anyone help in the comments?